# Google Oauth from my subdomain to my main domain

Tags: google-signin

I have an existing site sitename.com and an app for that site named app.sitename.com

We have already implemented the Google Sign-in in app.sitename.com and it works. I was just wondering if it is possible to get the signed in session from app.sitename.com and then use it in the main domain (sitename.com). I want  to make it so they only sign in once and some website content in the main domain will change/show depending whether they are signed in or not.

Thank you for your help!

We already have the Google Sign in the subdomain but we are not sure how to pass that authentication so it's also accessible in the main domain.